# Code to get single message from the queue in RabbitMQ using C#

Tags: rabbitmq

How to receive single message from the queue in RabbitMQ using C#

I am using the RabbitMQ to maintain my Queue.When I am read my queue messages its shows all massage present in the queue.

I want to retrieve single message as per First come first out criteria.

Please provide me code to get the single message from the queue by using RabbitMQ

```
var connection = connectionFactory.CreateConnection();
        var channel = connection.CreateModel();
        // accept only one unack-ed message at a time
        // uint prefetchSize, ushort prefetchCount, bool global
        channel.BasicQos(0, 1, false);
        MessageReceiver messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver(channel);
        channel.BasicConsume("viewer_Queues", false, messageReceiver);
        //channel.QueueDeclare("viewer_Queues", false, false, false, null);
        var consumer = new QueueingBasicConsumer(channel);
        channel.BasicConsume("viewer_Queues", true, consumer);
        BasicDeliverEventArgs ea = (BasicDeliverEventArgs)consumer.Queue.Dequeue();
        var body = ea.Body;
        var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
        Console.WriteLine(message + " Received.");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this, from the website Tutorials in the worker Queues Section:

```
`using System;
 using RabbitMQ.Client;
 using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Threading;

 class Worker
 {
  public static void Main()
  {
    var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost" };
    using(var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    using(var channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "task_queue",
                             durable: true,
                             exclusive: false,
                             autoDelete: false,
                             arguments: null);

        channel.BasicQos(prefetchSize: 0, prefetchCount: 1, global: false);

        Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for messages.");

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
        {
            var body = ea.Body;
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Received {0}", message);

            int dots = message.Split('.').Length - 1;
            Thread.Sleep(dots * 1000);

            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Done");

            channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
        };
        channel.BasicConsume(queue: "task_queue",
                             autoAck: false,
                             consumer: consumer);

        Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}`

the prefetch argument is important if you want to get only one message at a time you can read about it in the official website https://www.rabbitmq.com/

Comment: Thank you for the above code. I use same code mention above still I am getting all messages in the queue. I want messages based on FIFO . I want to get one by one message .Single message at a time .Please suggest